# All GraphlQL queries not executing if any query gets interrupted

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am using GraphQl Apollo client and React. I have to run multiple queries on an array of IDs, and for that I am using for of, and when rendered if the loop completes everything runs fine , but if loop could not complete as if user switch to some other page, and later if user comes back to the page , whole loop runs but some requests don't execute. I even tried aborting pending requests but still same issue. If initially only two requests run and others didn't, later when user returns only two requests have executed.

I can not use Promise.all because i need to to render data one by one.

Here is my code:

```
export default function OrganizationList() {
  
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const isGuest = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.utils.isGuest);
    const isOrgSelected = useSelector(
      (state: RootState) => state.utils.isOrgSelected
    );
    const currentProfile = useSelector(
      (state: RootState) => state.profile.currentProfile
    );

    const [orgs, setOrgs] = useState<Profile[]>([]);
  
    //GRAPHQL
    const [organizationList, setOrganizationList] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [profiles,setProfiles] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(()=>{
      return ()=>{
        setOrganizationList([]);
      }
    },[location.pathname]);
  
    const [abortController, setAbortController] = useState(new AbortController());
  
  
    useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
        abortController.abort();
      };
    }, [abortController]);
    
    const handleBeforeUnload = () => {
      abortController.abort();
    };
  
    useEffect(()=>{
      const cacheData = apolloClient.cache.extract();
  
      console.log('cached',cacheData);
  
      
    },[])
    
    const getProfileInfoHandler = async (profiles:string[]) => {
  
  
      try {
        let mergedDataArr = [];
        
        for (const val of profiles) {
          setIsLoading(true);
          
  
          const orgProfileDataRes = await apolloClient.query({
            query: ORG_PROFILE_DATA_QUERY,
            fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
            variables: {
              profileAddress: val,
            },
            context: {
              fetchOptions: {
                signal: abortController.signal,
              },
            },
          });
          const orgProfileData = orgProfileDataRes.data;
    
          const allChallengesForOrgDataRes = await apolloClient.query({
            query: ALL_CHALLENGES_FOR_ORG_QUERY,
            fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
            variables: {
              profileAddress: val,
              
            },
            
          });
          const allChallengesForOrgData = allChallengesForOrgDataRes.data;
    
          const mergedData = {
            ...orgProfileData.fetchOrgProfileData,
            challenges: allChallengesForOrgData.fetchAllChallengesForOrg,
            profileId: val,
          };
          mergedDataArr.push(mergedData);
          setOrganizationList(prev=>[...prev,mergedData])
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
        // setTest(mergedDataArr);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("this error is from list", err);
      }
    };
  
    useEffect(()=>{
      // alert('run fetch');
      if(profiles.length){
        getProfileInfoHandler(profiles)
      }
    },[profiles,location.pathname])
  
  
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ALL_ORG_PROFILES, {
      errorPolicy: "all",
      fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
      onCompleted: (data) => {
        setProfiles([...data?.allProfiles])
      },
      onError:(error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (location.pathname === USER_ORG_PROFILE_LIST_PATH) {
        setOrgs(
          organizationList.filter((org) =>
            currentProfile.organizations.includes(org.profileId)
          )
        );
      } else {
        setOrgs(organizationList);
      }
    }, [organizationList, location.pathname, currentProfile.organizations]);
  
    return !orgs.length ? (
      <div className="text-center flex h-full items-center justify-center dark:bg-black">
        <Spinner size="xl" className="self-center" />
      </div>
    ) : orgs.length ? (
      <div className="flex justify-center md:block md:px-9">
        <div className="p-2 sm:p-4 flex flex-col justify-center lg:grid grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-x-2 xl:gap-x-6 gap-y-2 xl:gap-y-6  dark:text-white">
          {orgs &&
            orgs?.map((org, index) => (
              <OrganizationCard organization={org} key={index} />
            ))}
          {isLoading ? (
            <div className="text-center flex h-full items-center justify-center dark:bg-black p-5">
              <Spinner size="xl" className="self-center" />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <EmptyList
        text="It's quiet silent here..."
        showButton={!isOrgSelected && !isGuest}
        buttonText="Create Organization"
        ButtonIcon={TbPlus}
        handleButtonClick={() => {
          navigate(ORG_PROFILE_CREATE_PATH);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

I am trying to achieve functionality such that initially all caches get stored and when user comes to the page again , if something is not in cache it requests again. I have tried all fetch policies but getting same issue .